# How can I split an attribute's value within LINQ(-to-XML)?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml, delicious-api

I've been feeling like start doing some fun stuff with my delicious bookmarks and LINQ to XML, and I was wondering if there's a way to split the tag attribute *within* LINQ.

What I've meant with *split the tag within LINQ* was generating a collection of strings for each post element, so the expected result would be a generic collection of `post` elements, with its attributes as properties, where the `tag` property is itself another collection of strings, with its items being each tag.

For those not quite familiar with delicious.com's exported xml, here´s the basic structure of an element:

```
<post
    href="http://stackoverflow.com/"
    hash="e4a42d992025b928a586b8bdc36ad38d"
    description="Stack Overflow"
    tag="code development programming community tips answers reference"
    time="2009-05-22T19:44:09Z"
    extended="Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site that's free."
    meta="e0bf85c9df073cd51cc5528637db5277"
 />
```

Here's the snippet of code I'm using:

```
   XDocument delicious = XDocument.Load("all.xml");

  var bookmarks = from posts in delicious.Descendants().Attributes("tag")
                  select (string)posts;
```

Any ideas, suggestions, comments would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your desired output actually like?  Do you want an array of each value in the "tag" field?

```
var bookmarks = from posts in delicious.Descendants().Attributes("tag")
                    select ((string)posts).Split(" ");
```

That would give you a list of arrays.   It's hard to say how to accomplish what you want, since it isn't very well specified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew, actually I want to be able to compute those tags like if they were independent, say, how many "development" tags I've added in a particular month, et cétera.

Comment: You could get the string and add a where clause with Contains " development ". That will get you posts with attributes having development as part of its tag.

Comment: Thank you shahkalpesh! I've been thinking about this approach which at the moment is probably the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

string class has a Split method.
Is this what you are looking for?

EDIT: string.Join(Environment.NewLine, bookmarks.ToArray());

Comment: Not really, actually I need to split them *within* LINQ so I can expose them to its operators such as count() and sum()

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to use 'set' and assign the value to that variable, and then used set to continue to manipulate, so at the end I was able to just use it in my linq query, as it was in a form that was now useful to me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution James! mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to respond, but here is something I did:
           var q = from file in Directory.GetFiles(...)
                    let fi = new FileInfo(file)
                    let c = XElement.Load(file) as XElement
                    let livetime = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Element("LiveTime").Value) ? int.Parse(c.Element("LiveTime").Value) : -1
                    select new
                    {
                        DeadTime = deadtime,

By using set you can do manipulations on the attribute.